# Android reverse tethering is not working?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, windows, reverse-tether

I have been trying to share windows pc internet to my android tablet( I Ball Slide, Jellybean) over usb, there is an option in "settings" to share internet[image: image attached], but I can't use internet in my device. When I open "Network and Sharing center", screenshot is given below[image]
It shows two networks, firt one has access to the internet and the second one doesn't, also the second network is an unidentified network. From the Status of the unidentified network, you can see that there has been no data received, the device is sending no data, why it is so?
I haven't rooted my device for reverse tethering(and I do not know whether it is rooted or not), the option was there.
What should I do to make it work?
(win 7 ultimate 64bit)
UPDATE: Other users say that the option in the first image named **USB Internet** is for sharing android device's internet to pc, to clarify this, I am uploading these two images.  This is the first picture before connecting the usb cable[image]

and this is the screen shot of the menu for USB tethering[image]

Comment: Is your device rooted? If yes, there is an alternate way to get reverse tethering on Windows.

Comment: @ItsmePawan Whys another way?  The manufacturer has already given an option to do so. Meanwhile, I do not know whether my device is rooted or not.

Comment: On SuperUser, you have 77 Reputation and therefore, you can set a bounty if your question did not receive enough attention. On the other hand, if you feel the question belongs more here then ask a moderator to migrate the question. About Cross-posting : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu